# image map access ID (area)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, dictionary

i have a image map and I want that the polygons will be highlighted until the next polygon is clicked.

like: click plogone 1 -become highlighted

than: click polygone 2 -becomes highlighted (polygon 1 is not highlighted)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.maphilight.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
 var nr = 0;
$('.map').maphilight({ strokeColor: 'ff0000', strokeWidth: 5});
$(polymap).click(function(e) {
            var data = $(high1).mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
            data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
            $(high1).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
            });
  });
```

```
</head>
  <body>
    <br>
    <img class="map" src="pb90%20%28150%29.html.png" ismap="ismap" usemap="#mapmap" alt="html imagemap created with QGIS" border="0">
    <map id="polymap" name="mapmap">
      <area id='high1'  shape="poly" href="PDF1.pdf" target="cont" coords="834,366,837,363,840" alt="">
      <area id='high2'  shape="poly" href="PDF2.pdf" target="cont" coords="940,236,941,236" alt="">
      <area id='high3'  shape="poly" href="PDF3.pdf" target="cont" coords="831,345,828,348,824" alt="">
....
```

My problem is that I can't access the ID of the areas. If you click the polygons only the area with "high1" will be high lighted.
So instead of that

```
$(high1).
```

I would need a kind of event handler.

It would be really cool If someone knows a solution :-)

cheers Immanuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jquery selector can be on `area`, and then the function that would run on the click event would be dependent on the area you clicked.  Within your function, you can use the `this` keyword to refer to the calling object.

```
   $('area').click(function (e) {
        var data = $(this).mouseout().data('maphilight') || {};
        data.alwaysOn = !data.alwaysOn;
        $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight');
    });
```